# Need coding to change the row number based off of row that Username is entered in to guarantee the correct data is being copied

Tags: vba, excel

I have a report that I am pulling from currently using an exact column and row however, I need VBA to find the row number for the designated Username (located in column A) and only pull the data from that row in other columns. The reason for this is because when a user is deleted/added, the data shifts up or down on the sheet. This is what I currently have and I don't know where to begin.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim xDate As String
Dim ACD As String
Dim Untouched As String
Dim DailyAct As String
Dim SchedAdherence As String
Dim Status As String
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim DailyPerformance As Excel.Workbook
Dim TWB As Workbook
Set TWB = ThisWorkbook
Set DailyPerformance = Workbooks.Open("P:\DX\Daily Team Performance\Dignositc Team's Daily Performance Tracker (001).xlsx", ReadOnly:=True, Password:="dailyp123")



ACD = DailyPerformance.Worksheets("Matt's Tab Two").Range("C4").Value
DailyAct = DailyPerformance.Worksheets("Matt's Tab Two").Range("E4").Value
SchedAdherence = DailyPerformance.Worksheets("Matt's Tab Two").Range("F4").Value * 100
Status = DailyPerformance.Worksheets("1359 Report Summary").Range("B5").Value
xDate = DailyPerformance.Worksheets("1359 Report").Range("L2").Value

RowCount = TWB.Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
With TWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("B1")
.Offset(RowCount, 0) = xDate
.Offset(RowCount, 1) = ACD
.Offset(RowCount, 2) = DailyAct
.Offset(RowCount, 3) = SchedAdherence
.Offset(RowCount, 4) = Status
End With
TWB.Save
DailyPerformance.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Use the Range.Find method, then the .Row property of the range it returns: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel. You can record a macro to get the most of the code you'll need.

Comment: I am new to VBA and need an example of the coding if possible. I want it to find the correct username and then replace the row number for the columns I am copying the information from. Example: If (Rbunch) is on row 13 of column A, I need to copy from cell B13, N13, M13 and so on.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. @Absinthe provided information that will help you find your own solution. You should make an effort to use that information, instead of just saying *I need the code*. It's fine to need help sometimes, but please don't be helpless.

Comment: My wording is not the best and I apologize if you think I just want you to "write" the code. I am not understanding how to translate the range.find method into my copy line. Is there another reference that might help me with properly writing the copy line to use my row count for the range.find in place of an exact row #.
DailyPerformance.Worksheets("Matt's Tab Two").Range("E4").Value

("E4") to ("E (Range.find row count for username)")

Comment: @Blink21889 What you're asking for is really quite simple. Maybe you should read some beginners tutorials to get you started e.g. http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/excel_vba.html or https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you started in the right direction.

```
Sub FindCell()

    Dim UserNameString As String, UserNameCell As Range, MyRow As Long
    UserNameString = "AbC123"   'Place the value you're looking for

    'This will set the cell to the username value above
    Set UserNameCell = Sheet1.Cells.Find(UserNameString)

    MyRow = UserNameCell.Row

    MsgBox MyRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello K Davis. I understand that part but I am struggling to figure out how to use the MyRow in my formula in order to copy that specific row in another column.